# Ramification of assignment operators with values instead of references

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, move-semantics

This question comes from issues raised by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9746772/734069).

Normally, we define copy assignment operators for type `T` as `T& operator=(const T&)`, and move assignment operators for type `T` as `T& operator=(T&&)`.

However, what happens when we use a value parameter rather than a reference?

```
class T
{
public:
  T& operator=(T t);
};
```

This should make T both copy and move assignable. However, what I want to know is what are the language ramifications for `T`?

Specifically:

1. Does this count as a copy assignment operator for `T`, according to the specification?
2. Does this count as a move assignment operator for `T`, according to the specification?
3. Will `T` have a compiler-generated copy assignment operator?
4. Will `T` have a compiler-generated move assignment operator?
5. How does this affect traits classes like `std::is_move_assignable`?

Comment: Related discussion: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value

Comment: I get compiler errors on both Visual Studio and g++ if I have something both T& operator = (T t) and T& operator = (T && t) since it is ambiguous

Comment: @user929404: And you should. The point is that you replace *both* the copy and move assignment with just value assignment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most of this is described in §12.8. Paragraph 17 defines what counts as user-declared copy assignment operators:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&`, or `const volatile X&`.

Paragraph 19 defines what counts as user-declared move assignment operators:

> A user-declared move assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static
>   non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of
>   type `X&&`, `const X&&`, `volatile X&&`, or `const volatile X&&`.

So, it counts as a copy assignment operator, but not as a move assignment operator.

Paragraph 18 tells when the compiler generates copy assignment operators:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment
>   operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares
>   a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly
>   declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it
>   is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the
>   class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared
>   destructor.

Paragraph 20 tells us when the compiler generates move assignment operators:

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move
>   assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if
>   and only if
>   [...]
>   — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   [...]

Since the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator, neither of the implicit ones will be generated by the compiler.

`std::is_copy_assignable` and `std::is_move_assignable` are described in table 49 as having the same value as, respectively `is_assignable<T&,T const&>::value` and `is_assignable<T&,T&&>::value`. That table tells us that `is_assignable<T,U>::value` is `true` when:

> The expression `declval<T>() = declval<U>()` is well-formed when treated
>   as an unevaluated operand (Clause 5). Access checking is performed as
>   if in a context unrelated to `T` and `U`. Only the validity of the
>   immediate context of the assignment expression is considered.

Since both `declval<T&>() = declval<T const&>()` and `declval<T&>() = declval<T&&>()` are well-formed for that class, it still counts as copy assignable and move assignable.

As I mentioned in the comments, what's curious about all this is that, in the presence of a move constructor, that `operator=` will correctly perform moves, but technically not count as a move assignment operator. It's even stranger if the class has no copy constructor: it will have a copy assignment operator that doesn't do copies, but only moves.