# Double move on same object is copying from left to right?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, move-assignment-operator

I am just beginner in move operation in c++11, so playing with it. But found something which i am not able to understand.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        A(){cout << "default ctor" << endl;}
        A(const string& str):_str{str}{cout << "parameter ctor" << endl;}
        A(A&& obj):_str{std::move(obj._str)}{cout << "move ctor" << endl;}
        A& operator =(A&& rhs){_str = std::move(rhs._str);cout << "move assignment operation" << endl; return *this;}
        void print(){cout << _str << endl;}
    private:
        string _str;
};

int main(){
    A a("rupesh yadav"); // parameter ctor
    A b(std::move(a));   // move ctor

    cout << "print a: ";
    a.print();           // NOT printing  --> CORRECT!!
    cout << "print b: ";
    b.print();           // printing      --> CORRECT!!

    b = std::move(a);    // i don't know may be silly but still lets do it WHY NOT!!!, could be just mistake??

    cout << "print a: "; 
    a.print();           // printing      --> WRONG!! 
    cout << "print b: "; 
    b.print();           // NOT printing  --> WRONG!!
}
```

I was expecting that `b = std::move(a)` operation would behave something different because i am applying move on object **a** second time but it is copying left side object **b** to right hand side object **a**, this part i don't understand.

Or i have done something wrong in programming.
Please help if i am doing something wrong in move operation.

**EDIT:** I know this is undefined behavior. My doubt is if i will do it again then it is copying from object **a** to object **b**, and if again i will do the same thing then will copy object **b** to object **a**?

Hence it is copying form left to right and right to left why?

Comment: It is not undefined behavior. The internal implementation of std::string's move assignment operator  seems to use swap on your platform.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6687388/951890

Answer (score 6):

You can't move from the same object twice.

After you first moved `a` into `b`, `a` had a "valid but unspecified state" (can't remember the exact terminology). Then, you attempted to move `a` into `b` *again*! Now all heck has broken loose. (I suspect that, internally, the data pointers have just been swapped around.)

Simply don't do this. I see no reason to want to.

Comment: You're thinking of [17.3.28](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.valid): `an object state that is not specified except that the object's invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified for its type`, also [17.6.5.15](http://eel.is/c++draft/lib.types.movedfrom): `Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from ([class.copy]). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.`

Comment: The rule only applies to the standard library. This implies that it's a constraint on library developers but doesn't make it safe to do so in general.

Comment: @user6292850: Sounds about right. And `std::string` is part of the standard library.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i know this is undefined behavior but it is behaving like defined :) .

Comment: @RupeshYadav.: Doing what you dream about is one possible symptom of undefined behaviour. Doesn't make it defined.

Comment: What I mean is "leave in a valid but unspecified state" is something required for the implementator. The language doesn't prevent you from moving from a string object twice, but prevents the users from calling operations that have preconditions (i.e, `front()` requires `empty()` should be false)

Comment: @user6292850: Oh I meant logically. Once you've moved Data from X to Y, Data is no longer in X so you can't move it from X to Y again. I don't really see the purpose of what the OP's asking tbh.

Comment: @user6292850 say someone wrongly moved twice then what would be the behavior, at least my called by object should not be changed.. my concern is here it is changing my called by object which is undesired..

Comment: @RupeshYadav: Moving (potentially) modifies both the source and the target and the source is modified in an unspecified manner. So you really shouldn't expect anything about the CONTENT of a moved from object(irrespective of how often you move from it)

Comment: @MikeMB this sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing prevents you from moving from an object twice. Standard library objects are required to be left in a "valid, but unspecified" state when moved from. The only condition is that "the object's invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified for its type" [17.3.28](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.valid). As an example, the move constructor for [`std::string`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.cons#2) says:

> `basic_string(const basic_string& str);`
>
> `basic_string(basic_string&& str) noexcept;`
>
> 2 *Effects*: Constructs an object of class `basic_string` as indicated
>   in Table [tab:strings.ctr.cpy]. In the second form, `str` is left in a
>   valid state with an unspecified value.

The move constructor  has no preconditions and moving from it again would not violate its invariants. Furthermore, since it's clearly outlined in the standard, by definition it's not undefined behavior. You could argue by omission that violating the invariants of `std::string` is undefined behavior however, but that leads us to:

Is calling `operator<<` on a `std::string` disallowed? The description from [`cppreference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) says:

> Behaves as a
>   [FormattedOutputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedOutputFunction).
>   After constructing and checking the sentry object, determines the
>   output format padding as follows:
>
> - If `str.size()` is not less than `os.width()`, uses the range `[str.begin(), str.end())` as-is
> - Otherwise, if `(os.flags() & ios_base::adjustfield) == ios_base::left`, places `os.width()-str.size()` copies of the
>     `os.fill()` character after the character sequence
> - Otherwise, places `os.width()-str.size()` copies of the `os.fill()` character before the character sequence

[`size()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.capacity#3), [`begin()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.iterators#1) and [`end()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.iterators#2) have no preconditions so the code is perfectly safe.