# Move Semantics: post set nullptr

Tags: pointers, c++11, move-semantics

Is there something akin to the *post increment* operator to set an origin pointer to null ?

Wanted behaviour:

```
Class MyClass{
   public:
   int * ptr;

   MyClass( MyClass && origin) noexcept;
   MyClass(){}
};

MyClass::MyClass( MyClass && origin) noexcept:
   ptr(origin.ptr){origin.ptr=nullptr};
```

Workaround with wanted semantic:

```
int * moveptr(int * & ptr){
        int * auxptr=ptr;
        ptr=nullptr;
        return auxptr;
}

MyClass::MyClass( MyClass && origin) noexcept: ptr(moveptr( origin.ptr)){};
```

Maybe I'm missing something from the standard, but I couldn't find anything to represent a type of pointer to represent *not ownership* but also the prevents accidental *sharing* of a pointer.

I could use an unique_ptr with a custom deleter that does nothing, but that'd make the original assignment of the pointer weird.

Comment: does it really bother you to write that one extra line `rhs.p = nullptr`?

Comment: It's not a matter of bothering, rather of forgetting to do it.

Comment: anyway it's the idiomatic thing to do, I doubt it has any premade solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in C++, you have to write it yourself as you had with `moveptr`. This is the same case when you use `delete ptr;`, some programmers would like to automatically set `ptr` to `nullptr` but `delete` will not do it.

Another aproach used by some coders is to use `swap`:

```
MyClass::MyClass( MyClass && origin) noexcept : ptr(nullptr)
   { swap(origin); };   


class MyClass {
   // ...
   inline void swap(MyClass & other) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(ptr, other.ptr);
   }
   // ...
};
```

but before using it, read on whether its worth it:

http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html

[Why do some people use swap for move assignments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687388/why-do-some-people-use-swap-for-move-assignments)

Comment: I prefer `std::exchange`: `MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&& origin) : ptr(std::exchange(origin.ptr, nullptr)) noexcept { }`